# What really is the speed of light in a medium/vacuum, group or phase velocity?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction, dispersion, phase-velocity

While reading about refractive index 2 terms popped up, group velocity which alway slows down in a medium and phase velocity which may exceed speed of light. Say in a complete vacuum and using laser with only 1 frequency as an example, which of the two kinds of velocity is defined as standard $c$ in physics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is that in a vacuum for light, the two are equivalent. If you solve Maxwell's equations in a vacuum what you will find is that

$$ E(x,t) = E_0 \cos(kx - \omega t) $$

likewise for the magnetic field (in magnitude). You will also find that these solve maxwell's equations only when

$$\frac{\omega}{k} \equiv v_p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}} = c $$

That is, in a vacuum $\omega = c k$. From which is follows that

$$ \frac{d\omega}{dk} \equiv v_g = c $$

as well.

To answer your question directly, what we usually mean by "speed of light" is the *group* velocity, as this is the one that Einstein's postulate says should be constant (the max speed at which *information* can be transmitted). So while we could define *the number* either way I think it's convention to define the speed of light in vacuum to be referring to the group velocity.

Having said that, with respect to your question about what ***really*** is the speed of light in a medium/vacuum, that's not ontologically the right question to ask. That is, it's not that one exists in any more fundamental sense than the other. There are simply **two different** velocities and we always need to specify which one we are talking about.

Answer (score 5):

Even though the question in the text has a simple answer (phase and group velocity in vacuum are the same, due to the linear dispersion), the  general question put in the title ( What really is the speed of light in a medium/vacuum, group or phase velocity? ) has a much more complex answer in the case of a medium.

The case of anomalous dispersion makes clear that in some cases even [the group velocity may become higher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics)#Group_and_phase_velocity) than $c$. In such cases, the relevant velocity (the speed  of energy and information transfer) is something else. Quite often, people refer to the *signal velocity* as the appropriate generalization. However one has to notice that, under such extreme dispersion condition, the deformation with time of a wavepacket may be significant and up to nine different velocities have been identified. In the classical Jackson's textbook on electrodynamics you may find the definition of a couple of these additional velocities (the forerunners velocities).

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about these subtleties, and I do want to make that clear. The signal velocity is the appropriate generalization, and I just didn't want to get into Jackson level stuff given the level of the question :)