An object with mass cannot travel with the speed of light in vacuum but what if lights speed in a medium is below the object's speed?
I read in my Physics textbook that when light falls perpendicularly on an optically denser medium it doesn't change its path rather it's speed slows down. If after multiple refractions the speed of light becomes equal to the speed of the object, what will happen? What if the speed of light was never $c$ and was equal to 700,000 km/h (the speed of Parker Solar Prove, a NASA spacecraft)? If it were 700,000 km/h, would it not defy the concept of an object not travelling with the speed of light? If you use some complex mathematics, please do explain them, because I might not be familiar with them.

An object with mass cannot travel at the speed of light in  vacuum.

$c$ is a constant, $299,792,458,\mathrm{m},\mathrm{s}^{-1}$. You can’t travel faster than that in flat spacetime because of spacetime’s geometry. That’s the only rule.

This question is similar to: What happens if light/particles exceeded the speed of light for a particular medium?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/566615/

A massive object can't travel faster than c, the speed of light in vacuum, which is a universal constant.
An object can travel through some medium faster than the speed of light in that medium. When it does, it emits Cherenkov radiation — the characteristic blue glow of nuclear reactors — much as an object traveling faster than the speed of sound in a medium emits a sonic boom.


If after multiple refractions the speed of light becomes equal to the speed of the object, what will happen?

You don't need multiple refractions. This is a common scenario in nuclear reactors. They are very often placed in a pool of water, and the electrons that are ejected travel faster than the speed of light in the water. They produce a characteristic blue glow called Cherenkov radiation.

This does not violate relativity. The invariant speed $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum. It is the invariance of $c$ which leads to all of the relativistic effects, not the fact that light goes that speed in vacuum. If the photon were eventually found to have some small (very small) mass, then $c$ would not be the speed of light even in vacuum, but it would still be the invariant speed and all relativistic effects would hold.

Just another correct answer.

Can you explain how neutrons (with mass) can travel in this dense water faster than light in the water? (or perhaps a better way to word it is what causes light to travel slower than the neutrons.)  What is the physical mechanism that allows this?

@foolishmuse oops, I was wrong. I thought that they were neutrons, but upon looking at the energies involved even nuclear decay fast neutrons are usually not fast enough. It is electrons, not neutrons. I have corrected my answer

No problem. Even electrons have mass, so my question stands.

@foolishmuse the speed of light in water is about 0.75 c. This corresponds to a Lorentz factor of 1.5. An electron has a mass of about 500 keV/c^2. So any reaction that produces electrons with more than 250 keV of kinetic energy will do it. Many nuclear decays have that kind of energy, including free neutron decay, Bi-210, and K-37 (positron). Basically, if you push an electron with nuclear power, it can go faster than 0.75 c. When that happens in water, it glows

@foolishmuse How phase velocity works (your second wording) is kinda separate question. Let's just say it isn't nearly as important as c which is a universal constant, important not only for light.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/450377/what-really-is-the-speed-of-light-in-a-medium-vacuum-group-or-phase-velocity https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466/what-is-the-mechanism-behind-the-slowdown-of-light-photons-in-a-transparent-medi
